# How to duplicate xaml code dynamically on button click

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, duplicates

I am developing a xamarin application in which I have to duplicate same xaml code on button click with different id and text property. How can I achieve this?

Below is my xaml code which is a LinearLayout with a TextView and 2 ImageView.

On each button click I have to create the duplicate of this LinearLayout at the end with different id for each child and different text for TextView.

The LinearLayout is wrapped inside a RelativeLayout.
Please give me the C# ButtonClick code to achieve this?

```
    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:background="@drawable/img1"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="Test content"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6.5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/img3" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:src="@drawable/img2" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Android layouts are AXML, not XAML